I'm trying to identify a vehicle by the tail/brake lights, and the interior door panel
I'm looking to identify the make and model of this vehicle by the tail/brake lights, as well as the interior door panel.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.



Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Is the car in reverse in pic 1? The bumper lights look white. The Leaf (my "answer") has reverse lights near the tail lights as one would expect.

Looks like a Nissan Leaf, not sure which gen but 2019 has the tail lights which creep up the pillars of the hatch like an arrowhead.
